# Error in Queue Trigger - The input is not a valid Base-64 string

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-storage-queues, queuetrigger

I'm working in Azure Queue storage and  Azure functions queue trigger. I'm using the c# console project to send a class object as a message to the Azure queue and then setting up a queue trigger function to consume a class object in a queue.

But when I run it, it keeps showing that :

```
 Executed 'Function1' (Failed, Id=9134f8f9-0399-4049-a351-a5613b17aa12, Duration=35ms)[2023-06-10T07:38:48.866Z] 
 System.Private.CoreLib: Execution while executing function: MyQueueFunction. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'message'. System.Private.CoreLib: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an i illegal character among the padding characters.
```

This is the console code i used to send message to Azure Queue

```
public class Parameters
{
public string? Usersid { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    string connectionString = "<connectstring>";
    string queueName = "<Queuename>";

    QueueClientOptions options = new QueueClientOptions();
    options.Diagnostics.IsLoggingEnabled = false;

    QueueClient queueClient = new QueueClient(connectionString, queueName, options);

    var message = new Parameters
    {
        Usersid = "Kth7",        
    };
    string jsonMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);
    byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonMessage);
    string EncodedMessage = Convert.ToBase64String(messageBytes);
    try
    {
        await queueClient.SendMessageAsync(EncodedMessage);
        Console.WriteLine("Message sent");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Failed to send the message. Error: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
}
```

The code I used to consume messages via Azure Function Queue Trigger

```
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static async Task Run([QueueTrigger("<queuename>", Connection = "<constring>")]string message, ILogger log)
    {
        byte[] messageBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(message);
        string decodedMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(messageBytes);
        Parameters classObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Parameters>(decodedMessage);
        log.LogInformation($"Received message: userid={classObject.Usersid}");
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

I added encode and decode after I got this error but still, I'm getting this error. Do I need to change anything in my code? how to solve this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of encoding the JSON message and sending it as a string, you can directly send the serialized JSON object as a byte array. This eliminates the need for Base64 encoding and decoding.  That might help in narrowing it down to find the root cause of the error.

Comment: Did you try to set QueueClientOptions to set Message encoding? `QueueClientOptions options = new QueueClientOptions
{
    MessageEncoding = QueueMessageEncoding.Base64
};`

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

**`My console application code:`**

```
using Azure.Storage.Queues;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text;

public class Parameters
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string cs = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=rith;AccountKey=BT2tkeA==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
        string qn = "rithwik";

        QueueClientOptions o = new QueueClientOptions();
        o.Diagnostics.IsLoggingEnabled = false;

        QueueClient queueClient = new QueueClient(cs, qn, o);

        var msg = new Parameters
        {
           Name = "Rithwik Bojja",
        };
        string j = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msg);
        byte[] m = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(j);
        string EncodedMessage = Convert.ToBase64String(m);
        try
        {
            await queueClient.SendMessageAsync(EncodedMessage);
            Console.WriteLine("Message sent Rithwik, Please Check");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Failed to send the message and the Error is : {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

**`Now Azure Function App code:`**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FunctionApp31
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
        }
        public class MyM
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }

        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public void Run([QueueTrigger("rithwik", Connection = "con")] string myQueueItem)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
            MyM message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyM>(myQueueItem);
            _logger.LogInformation($"Received message: Name={message.Name}");

        }
    }
}
```

Now Firstly run the Azure Function app and the run or send the message using Console app:

**`Console app output:`**

[image]

**`Function App Output:`**

[image]

Try to follow above process and get the desired results as I have got.